# getElementById changes not going through on form submit

Tags: javascript, forms

Ok, so this is a continuation of my [How to hide the default value of a form field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34077643/how-to-hide-the-default-value-of-a-form-field]) question.  I've got a form where I sometimes need to change one of the values before submitting it to another website.  I used `getElementById` to do this, and it seemed to have worked, but then when the submission actually goes through the change hasn't been made.  Here's the code I used:

```
function changeAmount() {
  document.getElementById("amount").value = 50;
  form=document.getElementById('myform');
  form.target='_blank';
  form.action='http://www.example.com';
  form.submit();
}
```

I also tried taking out the submission code and putting the website in the action for the original form tag.  No dice.

So what's stopping the change from going through?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it would help if you would include the relevant part of the HTML.

Comment: Do you have <form onsubmit="changeAmount()"> ? You should be calling that function on submit of form.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML (in the question you link to) doesn't have any element with the ID *amount*, it has an element with the ID *Amount*. Identifiers are case sensitive.

(You have another issue in that you actually have three elements with that ID and IDs must be unique in a document).